How to boot into ubuntu 24.04 because it is not showing in grub menu after upgrade from 22.04
Here is the result of boot-repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w6yWm2NNQ6/
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20240905_1057]
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================
Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s
======================= Reinstall the grub2 of /dev/sda1 =======================
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7
==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/sda1 into the MBR of /dev/sda
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 229: /usr/lib/grub/grub-sort-version: not found
/etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen: 229: /usr/lib/grub/grub-sort-version: not found
/etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen: 229: /usr/lib/grub/grub-sort-version: not found
Found memtest86+x64 image: /boot/memtest86+x64.bin
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg
Boot successfully repaired.
You can now reboot your computer.
The boot files of [sda1 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================
=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:        

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________
File system:       iso9660
Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                   sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                   core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                   location.
Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.

================================ 1 OS detected =================================
OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda1
================================ Host/Hardware =================================
CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)
===================================== UEFI =====================================
BIOS/UEFI firmware: V2.4(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).
============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================
Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________
sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________
sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________
sda1    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________
Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x000ef038
Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048  972607487 972605440 463.8G 83 Linux
sda2       972609534  976771071   4161538     2G  5 Extended
sda3       976773120 1953525167 976752048 465.8G 83 Linux
sda5       972609536  976771071   4161536     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 14.48 GiB, 15545139200 bytes, 30361600 sectors
Disk identifier: F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876F-C8245AF921E0
Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  9828451  9828388  4.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9828452  9838519    10068  4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9838520  9839119      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9842688 30361536 20518849  9.8G Linux filesystem
parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________
sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA WDC WD10EZEX-08M:;
1:1049kB:498GB:498GB:ext4::boot;
2:498GB:500GB:2131MB:::;
5:498GB:500GB:2131MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
3:500GB:1000GB:500GB:ext4::;
sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Kingston DataTraveler 2.0:;
1:32.8kB:5032MB:5032MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:5032MB:5037MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:5037MB:5038MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:5039MB:15.5GB:10.5GB:ext4::;
blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________
NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda
├─sda1 ext4     d3dcaddd-4711-4495-add9-7a06a411349e 000ef038-01
├─sda2                                               000ef038-02
├─sda3 ext4     a02d9383-80e7-4803-8ea4-43f2b15229c9 000ef038-03                          Data
└─sda5 swap     72d6e1ec-0f8d-4cce-a6dd-16ead62fd344 000ef038-05
sdb    iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64
├─sdb1 iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     F7DB-4D56                            f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876c-c8245af921e0                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     c70b6ebf-a425-49ed-bde4-eb449aa292c2 89571f78-dc05-e542-b716-eac409c58730 writable
Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________
                                                           Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1                                                      75.5G  78% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3                                                     389.8G  10% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________
/dev/sda1                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda3                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8
====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware
========================== sda1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================
 
/ was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d3dcaddd-4711-4495-add9-7a06a411349e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=72d6e1ec-0f8d-4cce-a6dd-16ead62fd344 none            swap    sw              0       0
======================= sda1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
        ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

55.348743439 = 59.430260736   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
426.527500153 = 457.980416000  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-generic                1
385.644603729 = 414.082740224  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic                 1
380.985347748 = 409.079902208  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  2
380.985347748 = 409.079902208  vmlinuz                                        2
426.527500153 = 457.980416000  vmlinuz.old                                    1
430.000972748 = 461.710028800  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-119-generic             7
376.618160248 = 404.390670336  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic              3
378.180660248 = 406.068391936  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               5
378.180660248 = 406.068391936  initrd.img                                     5
430.000972748 = 461.710028800  initrd.img.old                                 7
===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 10:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4 10:12 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4 10:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4 10:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5 11:36 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jun 26  2015 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

use boot-repair advanced options, and select purge grub before reinstall it. Ubuntu 22.04 is based on grub 2.06 while Ubuntu 24.04 is based on grub 2.12.  this make a conflict after upgrading the system.

tried your suggestion and it didn't help.  memtest doesn't show in the grub menu anymore which it used to before doing the advanced option. here is the link to the of result of boot-repair https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2Dj8KKhrnm/

From the result of the second boot-repair is attached to the comment:

Script /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new contains no commands and will do
nothing Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub and
/etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.

To solve this problem:

replace /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files with the same files from the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO file; mount the ISO file, open /casper directory, mount the minimal.squashfs, and copy /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files from mounted minimal.squashfs to your Ubuntu partition (dev/sda1).

Remove /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file, make the empty /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, and add these lines to it:



set default=0
set timeout=10
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='hd0,msdos1'
  linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro  
  initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu old kernel' --class ubuntu {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='hd0,msdos1'
  linux   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro  
  initrd  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-119-generic 
}



Save the file, reboot with Ubuntu, and update-grub, or use boot-repair again.


Thank you for the answer.  It solved the problem as we can now boot into the updated 24.04.  If we did #1 and #2, we cannot boot.  But if we did #1 partially by removing and not replacing from the ISO and #2, we can now boot.

Another problem we have is the apt update does not finish properly.
"Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if ... '
Sub-process returned an error code.   This seems to have some solutions somewhere in the forum.
